# 2.82a - Can't import multiple videos to sequence editor

Tags: import, video-sequence-editor, error

maybe a dumb question, but has anyone else had issues importing multiple video clips to the sequence editor in 2.8? With the older versions, you could select all clips in a directory using the A-key and they would import all clips in series. Beginning with 2.8, I get an error when using this same process. It seems like Blender is trying to load the directory instead of all the files in it maybe?

[image: videoimporterror]

Any thoughts? Maybe with the implementation of the new file browser, there's a setting i'm missing?
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in 2.83 beta. Grab it here: https://builder.blender.org/download/

Comment: Thanks! good to know it wasn't just me.